# Using p4a, how do i insert a row into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm using the p4a application framework, i need to insert rows into my database via fields that i have made previously, when the user presses submit, the database should update and thus other new rows should be able to to made etc.

I'm struggling to find how to input the data into the database, i can easily do it through putting the values into the sql statement but this is completely alien to me,

The code is:

```
public function submit()

{

    $location = $this->location->getNewValue();           
        $date = $this->date->getNewValue();
        $merono = $this->merono->getNewValue();

    $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO 'meetingrooms'(location, date, merono)
        VALUES
        ($location, $date, $merono)");


    p4a_db::singleton()->newRow($sql, array($location));

$this->load();
```

location, date and merono are all set in the fields i have created before this function and it should work as i have previously done the same for a login page, so i know the first section should be getting the variables. and as i have accessed the db previously i know that it is connecting, so it must be to do with the MySQL statement.

Thanks, 
Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out (even though this question was only active for a few mins XD)

the SQL statement was wrong for a start (Thanks to John Woo for the help (y)) now the statement goes:

```
query("INSERT INTO meetingrooms(location, date, merono)
        VALUES
        ('$location', '$date', '$merono')");
```

this successful statement allows for the variables placed into $location $date and $merono to be inserted into the table plus the extra addition to the start of the statement

goes as:

```
p4a_db::singleton()->
```

this calls the P4A database extension which in this pop-up class i have made, is not accessible,

so the full function now goes:-

```
public function submit()

{

    $location = $this->AreaName->getNewValue();
    $date = $this->date->getNewValue();
    $merono = $this->merono->getNewValue();

    p4a_db::singleton()->query("INSERT INTO meetingrooms(location, date, merono)
        VALUES
        ('$location', '$date', '$merono')");
```

Thanks for the help,

Steve.

Answer (score 2):

on your query, i found out that you are enclosing the table name with single quote, if you want to escape tableName or columnName use `backtick` instead,

```
INSERT INTO `meetingrooms`(location, date, merono)
       VALUES ($location, $date, $merono)
```

but since your tableName is not a reserved word or contains any invalid characters, you can get rid of the backtick.

If you are inserting values on the table which are not numeric, wrap it with single quotes,

```
INSERT INTO meetingrooms (location, date, merono)
       VALUES ('$location', '$date', '$merono')
```

Comment: no joy, i' will get back to you when I've fiddled a bit more with the code i made previous, i think it might be the bindings within the variables of the data i'm trying to insert into the table, i'm really not sure :\.